# Remove IP address from interface with VLANs

Tags: networking, arch-linux, vlan

On Arch Linux, I have a single physical ethernet interface on 2 VLANs (3 and 7) with static IP addresses for the VLANs and a DHCP address for the 'main' ethernet interface.

Is there a way for me to remove the IP address from eth0 and just have the VLANs? Or is there a way to assign eth0 to a VLAN? I'd prefer this to be done as part of the `/etc/netctl` or `/etc/systemd/network` configuration files.

The result of `ip addr` is:

> `1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default 
>       link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
>       inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
>       inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
>          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>   2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
>       link/ether 6c:ec:eb:5c:a3:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>       inet 192.168.106.55/24 brd 192.168.106.255 scope global eth0
>       inet6 fe80::6eec:ebff:fe5c:a30b/64 scope link 
>          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>   3: eth0.7@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
>       link/ether 6c:ec:eb:5c:a3:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>       inet 10.0.0.1/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global eth0.7
>       inet6 fe80::6eec:ebff:fe5c:a30b/64 scope link 
>          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
>   4: eth0.3@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
>       link/ether 6c:ec:eb:5c:a3:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
>       inet 192.168.1.7/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global eth0.3
>       inet6 fe80::6eec:ebff:fe5c:a30b/64 scope link 
>          valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

And the result of `ip -d link` is:

> `1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default 
>       link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00 promiscuity 0 
>   2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
>       link/ether 6c:ec:eb:5c:a3:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 
>   3: eth0.3@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
>       link/ether 6c:ec:eb:5c:a3:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 
>       vlan protocol 802.1q id 3 <REORDER_HDR> 
>   4: eth0.7@eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DEFAULT group default 
>       link/ether 6c:ec:eb:5c:a3:0b brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff promiscuity 0 
>       vlan protocol 802.1q id 7 <REORDER_HDR>`

Comment: I am not familiar with Arch so I can just guess. Have you tried deleting the configuration for `eth0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manually: `ifconfig $DEVICE 0.0.0.0 up` should remove the IP and leave the interface up and running.

Some distributions allow such a configuration statically, others do not.

Perhaps you can set up a **bridge**-device instead.

Comment: It would be better to use `ip link` / `ip addr` in answers as `ifconfig` is deprecated.

Comment: This did the trick. Making it permanent:

/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network to contain:
[Network]
DHCP=none
[Address]
Address=0.0.0.0/0